# Как изменить уровень подсветки экрана iPhone с помощью UISlider?

Tags: ios

Как изменить уровень подсветки экрана iPhone с помощью `UISlider`?

Comment: а что у вас уже есть? точнее вызывает проблемы работа с `UISlider` или `[UIScreen mainScreen].brightness`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создать слайдер:

```
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 100)];
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(changeBrightness:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:slider];
slider.value = [UIScreen mainScreen].brightness; //начальное значение
```

изменять значение:

```
- (void)changeBrightness:(UISlider*)sender
{
    [UIScreen mainScreen].brightness = sender.value;
}
```

Работает только на устройстве, не на симуляторе.